# Algebraic structures over groups and monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid

We define a vector space over a field and a module over a ring. But what algebraic structure is defined over a group?  over a monoid?  In case this can be done, could you give me examples?

Comment: Would you consider [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) or [representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) to be examples? (Both definitions makes sense for monoids as well.) It's not so clear what you're asking for here.

Comment: Ok, you guys closed my question and downvoted, but could someone explain WHY? I don't see why my question is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Vector spaces over fields are simply special cases of modules over rings, and modules over rings are in turn special examples of [modules over monoid objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monoid).

**Definition:** If $(C,\otimes,I)$ is a [monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), and $(X,\mu : X\otimes X\to X, e : I\to X)\in C$ is a [monoid in $C$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category), a *left module over $X$* is an object $N\in C$ together with a morphism $\rho : X\otimes N\to N$ such that
$$
\rho\circ(\operatorname{id}_X\otimes\rho) = \rho\circ(\mu\otimes\operatorname{id}_N)
$$
as morphisms $X\otimes X\otimes N\to N,$ and $\rho\circ(e\otimes\operatorname{id}_N) : I\otimes N\to N$ is equal to the unitor isomorphism.

**Example:** If $(C,\otimes, I) = (\mathsf{Ab},\otimes,\Bbb{Z})$ is the category of abelian groups with its usual tensor product, then a monoid $\mathcal{R}$ in $\mathsf{Ab}$ is equivalent to the data of a ring $R$, and the data of a left module over the monoid $\mathcal{R}$ is equivalent to the usual notion of a left module over the ring $R$. If $R = k$ is moreover a field, then the module is a $k$-vector space.

In this generality, monoids and groups may be thought of as special cases of monoid objects, in the monoidal category $(\mathsf{Set},\times,\{\ast\}).$ Unwinding the definitions above, a left module over a group or monoid $M$ is a set $S$ together with a function
\begin{align*}
-\cdot- : M\times S&\to S\\
(m,s)&\mapsto m\cdot s
\end{align*}
such that for all $m,n\in M$ and $s\in S,$ we have $m\cdot (n\cdot s) = (mn)\cdot s$ (this is the first condition in the definition), and if $e\in M$ is the identity, then $e\cdot s = s$ (this is the second condition).

If $M$ is a group, this is no more nor less than the notion of a [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on the set $S.$